# Selenium: How to paste URL onto a new tab - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am struggling to figure out a way to paste the text/URL onto a new tab in Chrome. I am running my tests on Linux in headless mode.
So, I was able to launch a new tab but unable to paste the URL on the navigation bar.

Why I am pasting URL? I have to click a button which will give me the URL, and I have to launch the URL on a new tab.

Here's the code I am trying to make it work.

```
    copyBtn.click(); //copying the URL
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");// launching a new tab
    SeleniumUtils.switchBrowserTab(driver, 1);
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND, "v").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform(); //sending the paste command 
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

The sysout is printing `about:blank` instead of the pasted text. I think its because I am not focussing on the navigation bar. I ready many blogs but seems like there is no way to focus on the navigation bar.
Could someone please throw some light on how can this use-case be achieved?

Also, I don't have the URL handy, to be honest i am not sure how can i get the copied URL. Because I am not running locally, i cannot use ToolKit.
Thank you.

Comment: if you have the url then how about:
replacing `"window.open()"` with `"window.open(" + url + ")"`

Comment: I don't have URL handy, clicking on the button copies the URL. I am not sure how can i retrieve it. Also, `copyBtn.getText()` doesn't give me the copied URL.

Comment: Try to use the java clipboard library

Answer (score 1):

This I used a lot:

```
public void openNewTab(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.open('');");
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

public void gotoTab(WebDriver driver, int tabIndex) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> winHandles = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandles.get(tabIndex));
}
```

---

```
WebDriver driver = ...;
openNewTab(driver);
gotoTab(driver, 1); // zero based
driver.get("...");
```